# Invalid JSON for Arabic text in data

Tags: json, arabic

I have this `data.json` file:

```
[{"interval": {"page": 1, "start": 1, "total": 21, "end": 10, "nb_pages": 3}, "ayas": {"1": {"stat": {"godnames": 1, "letters": 93, "words": 25}, "identifier": {"sura_name": "Al-Baqarah", "sura_arabic_name": "\u0627\u0644\u0628\u0642\u0631\u0629", "aya_id": 216, "sura_id": 2, "gid": 223}, "theme": {"topic": "\u0641\u0636\u0644 \u0627\u0644\u062c\u0647\u0627\u062f \u0648\u0627\u0644\u062f\u0639\u0648\u0629 \u0625\u0644\u064a\u0647", "subtopic": null, "chapter": "\u0627\u0644\u062c\u0647\u0627\u062f \u0641\u064a \u0627\u0644\u0625\u0633\u0644\u0627\u0645 "}, "aya": {"id": 216, "next_aya": {"sura_arabic": "\u0627\u0644\u0628\u0642\u0631\u0629", "text": "\u064a\u064e\u0633\u0652\u0623\u064e\u0644\u064f\u0648\u0646\u064e\u0643\u064e \u0639\u064e\u0646\u0650 \u0627\u0644\u0634\u0651\u064e\u0647\u0652\u0631\u0650 \u0627\u0644\u0652\u062d\u064e\u0631\u064e\u0627\u0645\u0650 \u0642\u0650\u062a\u064e\u0627\u0644\u064d \u0641\u0650\u064a\u0647\u0650 \u0642\u064f\u0644\u0652 \u0642\u0650\u062a\u064e\u0627\u0644\u064c \u0641\u0650\u064a\u0647\u0650 \u0643\u064e\u0628\u0650\u064a\u0631\u064c \u0648\u064e\u0635\u064e\u062f\u0651\u064c \u0639\u064e\u0646\u0652 \u0633\u064e\u0628\u0650\u064a\u0644\u0650 \u0627\u0644\u0644\u0651\u064e\u0647\u0650 \u0648\u064e\u0643\u064f\u0641\u0652\u0631\u064c \u0628\u0650\u0647\u0650 \u0648\u064e\u0627\u0644\u0652\u0645\u064e\u0633\u0652\u062c\u0650\u062f\u0650 \u0627\u0644\u0652\u062d\u064e\u0631\u064e\u0627\u0645\u0650 \u0648\u064e\u0625\u0650\u062e\u0652\u0631\u064e\u0627\u062c\u064f \u0623\u064e\u0647\u0652\u0644\u0650\u0647\u0650 \u0645\u0650\u0646\u0652\u0647\u064f \u0623\u064e\u0643\u0652\u0628\u064e\u0631\u064f \u0639\u0650\u0646\u0652\u062f\u064e \u0627\u0644\u0644\u0651\u064e\u0647\u0650 \u0648\u064e\u0627\u0644\u0652\u0641\u0650\u062a\u0652\u0646\u064e\u0629\u064f \u0623\u064e\u0643\u0652\u0628\u064e\u0631\u064f \u0645\u0650\u0646\u064e \u0627\u0644\u0652\u0642\u064e\u062a\u0652\u0644\u0650 \u0648\u064e\u0644\u064e\u0627 \u064a\u064e\u0632\u064e\u0627\u0644\u064f\u0648\u0646\u064e \u064a\u064f\u0642\u064e\u0627\u062a\u0650\u0644\u064f\u0648\u0646\u064e\u0643\u064f\u0645\u0652 \u062d\u064e\u062a\u0651\u064e\u0649 \u064a\u064e\u0631\u064f\u062f\u0651\u064f\u0648\u0643\u064f\u0645\u0652 \u0639\u064e\u0646\u0652 \u062f\u0650\u064a\u0646\u0650\u0643\u064f\u0645\u0652 \u0625\u0650\u0646\u0650 \u0627\u0633\u0652\u062a\u064e\u0637\u064e\u0627\u0639\u064f\u0648\u0627 \u0648\u064e\u0645\u064e\u0646\u0652 \u064a\u064e\u0631\u0652\u062a\u064e\u062f\u0650\u062f\u0652 \u0645\u0650\u0646\u0652\u0643\u064f\u0645\u0652 \u0639\u064e\u0646\u0652 \u062f\u0650\u064a\u0646\u0650\u0647\u0650 \u0641\u064e\u064a\u064e\u0645\u064f\u062a\u0652 \u0648\u064e\u0647\u064f\u0648\u064e \u0643\u064e\u0627\u0641\u0650\u0631\u064c \u0641\u064e\u0623\u064f\u0648\u0644\u064e\u0626\u0650\u0643\u064e \u062d\u064e\u0628\u0650\u0637\u064e\u062a\u0652 \u0623\u064e\u0639\u0652\u0645\u064e\u0627\u0644\u064f\u0647\u064f\u0645\u0652 \u0641\u0650\u064a \u0627\u0644\u062f\u0651\u064f\u0646\u0652\u064a\u064e\u0627 \u0648\u064e\u0627\u0644\u0652\u0622\u062e\u0650\u0631\u064e\u0629\u0650 \u0648\u064e\u0623\u064f\u0648\u0644\u064e\u0626\u0650\u0643\u064e \u0623\u064e\u0635\u0652\u062d\u064e\u0627\u0628\u064f \u0627\u0644\u0646\u0651\u064e\u0627\u0631\u0650 \u0647\u064f\u0645\u0652 \u0641\u0650\u064a\u0647\u064e\u0627 \u062e\u064e\u0627\u0644\u0650\u062f\u064f\u0648\u0646\u064e", "sura": "Al-Baqarah", "id": 217}, "text_no_highlight": "\u0643\u062a\u0628 \u0639\u0644\u064a\u0643\u0645 \u0627\u0644\u0642\u062a\u0627\u0644 \u0648\u0647\u0648 \u0643\u0631\u0647 \u0644\u0643\u0645 \u0648\u0639\u0633\u0649 \u0623\u0646 \u062a\u0643\u0631\u0647\u0648\u0627 \u0634\u064a\u0626\u0627 \u0648\u0647\u0648 \u062e\u064a\u0631 \u0644\u0643\u0645 \u0648\u0639\u0633\u0649 \u0623\u0646 \u062a\u062d\u0628\u0648\u0627 \u0634\u064a\u0626\u0627 \u0648\u0647\u0648 \u0634\u0631 \u0644\u0643\u0645 \u0648\u0627\u0644\u0644\u0647 \u064a\u0639\u0644\u0645 \u0648\u0623\u0646\u062a\u0645 \u0644\u0627 \u062a\u0639\u0644\u0645\u0648\u0646", "prev_aya": {"sura_arabic": "\u0627\u0644\u0628\u0642\u0631\u0629", "text": "\u064a\u064e\u0633\u0652\u0623\u064e\u0644\u064f\u0648\u0646\u064e\u0643\u064e \u0645\u064e\u0627\u0630\u064e\u0627 \u064a\u064f\u0646\u0652\u0641\u0650\u0642\u064f\u0648\u0646\u064e \u0642\u064f\u0644\u0652 \u0645\u064e\u0627 \u0623\u064e\u0646\u0652\u0641\u064e\u0642\u0652\u062a\u064f\u0645\u0652 \u0645\u0650\u0646\u0652 \u062e\u064e\u064a\u0652\u0631\u064d \u0641\u064e\u0644\u0650\u0644\u0652\u0648\u064e\u0627\u0644\u0650\u062f\u064e\u064a\u0652\u0646\u0650 \u0648\u064e\u0627\u0644\u0652\u0623\u064e\u0642\u0652\u0631\u064e\u0628\u0650\u064a\u0646\u064e \u0648\u064e\u0627\u0644\u0652\u064a\u064e\u062a\u064e\u0627\u0645\u064e\u0649 \u0648\u064e\u0627\u0644\u0652\u0645\u064e\u0633\u064e\u0627\u0643\u0650\u064a\u0646\u0650 \u0648\u064e\u0627\u0628\u0652\u0646\u0650 \u0627\u0644\u0633\u0651\u064e\u0628\u0650\u064a\u0644\u0650 \u0648\u064e\u0645\u064e\u0627 \u062a\u064e\u0641\u0652\u0639\u064e\u0644\u064f\u0648\u0627 \u0645\u0650\u0646\u0652 \u062e\u064e\u064a\u0652\u0631\u064d \u0641\u064e\u0625\u0650\u0646\u0651\u064e \u0627\u0644\u0644\u0651\u064e\u0647\u064e \u0628\u0650\u0647\u0650 \u0639\u064e\u0644\u0650\u064a\u0645\u064c", "sura": "Al-Baqarah", "id": 215}, "recitation": "https://www.everyayah.com/data/Abdul_Basit_Murattal_64kbps/002216.mp3", "translation": null, "text": "\u0643\u064f\u062a\u0650\u0628\u064e \u0639\u064e\u0644\u064e\u064a\u0652\u0643\u064f\u0645\u064f \u0627\u0644\u0652\u0642\u0650\u062a\u064e\u0627\u0644\u064f \u0648\u064e\u0647\u064f\u0648\u064e <span class=\"match term0\">\u0643\u064f\u0631\u0652\u0647\u064c</span> \u0644\u064e\u0643\u064f\u0645\u0652 \u0648\u064e\u0639\u064e\u0633\u064e\u0649 \u0623\u064e\u0646\u0652 <span class=\"match term1\">\u062a\u064e\u0643\u0652\u0631\u064e\u0647\u064f\u0648\u0627</span> \u0634\u064e\u064a\u0652\u0626\u064b\u0627 \u0648\u064e\u0647\u064f\u0648\u064e \u062e\u064e\u064a\u0652\u0631\u064c \u0644\u064e\u0643\u064f\u0645\u0652 \u0648\u064e\u0639\u064e\u0633\u064e\u0649 \u0623\u064e\u0646\u0652 \u062a\u064f\u062d\u0650\u0628\u0651\u064f\u0648\u0627 \u0634\u064e\u064a\u0652\u0626\u064b\u0627 \u0648\u064e\u0647\u064f\u0648\u064e \u0634\u064e\u0631\u0651\u064c \u0644\u064e\u0643\u064f\u0645\u0652 \u0648\u064e\u0627\u0644\u0644\u0651\u064e\u0647\u064f \u064a\u064e\u0639\u0652\u0644\u064e\u0645\u064f \u0648\u064e\u0623\u064e\u0646\u0652\u062a\u064f\u0645\u0652 \u0644\u064e\u0627 \u062a\u064e\u0639\u0652\u0644\u064e\u0645\u064f\u0648\u0646\u064e"}, "position": {}, "sajda": {"type": null, "exist": false, "id": null}, "annotations": {}, "sura": {}}, "2": {"stat": {"godnames": 1, "letters": 157, "words": 35}, "identifier": {"sura_name": "An-Nisa'", "sura_arabic_name": "\u0627\u0644\u0646\u0633\u0627\u0621", "aya_id": 19, "sura_id": 4, "gid": 512}, "theme": {"topic": "\u0627\u0644\u0645\u0633\u0627\u0648\u0627\u0629 \u0628\u064a\u0646 \u0627\u0644\u0631\u062c\u0644 \u0648\u0627\u0644\u0645\u0631\u0623\u0629 \u0641\u064a \u0627\u0644\u062a\u0643\u0627\u0644\u064a\u0641 \u0648\u0627\u0644\u0648\u0627\u062c\u0628\u0627\u062a ", "subtopic": null, "chapter": "\u062d\u0642\u0648\u0642 \u0627\u0644\u0625\u0646\u0633\u0627\u0646 "}, "aya": {"id": 19, "next_aya": {"sura_arabic": "\u0627\u0644\u0646\u0633\u0627\u0621", "text": "\u0648\u064e\u0625\u0650\u0646\u0652 \u0623\u064e\u0631\u064e\u062f\u0652\u062a\u064f\u0645\u064f \u0627\u0633\u0652\u062a\u0650\u0628\u0652\u062f\u064e\u0627\u0644\u064e \u0632\u064e\u0648\u0652\u062c\u064d \u0645\u064e\u0643\u064e\u0627\u0646\u064e \u0632\u064e\u0648\u0652\u062c\u064d \u0648\u064e\u0622\u062a\u064e\u064a\u0652\u062a\u064f\u0645\u0652 \u0625\u0650\u062d\u0652\u062f\u064e\u0627\u0647\u064f\u0646\u0651\u064e \u0642\u0650\u0646\u0652\u0637\u064e\u0627\u0631\u064b\u0627 \u0641\u064e\u0644\u064e\u0627 \u062a\u064e\u0623\u0652\u062e\u064f\u0630\u064f\u0648\u0627 \u0645\u0650\u0646\u0652\u0647\u064f \u0634\u064e\u064a\u0652\u0626\u064b\u0627 \u0623\u064e\u062a\u064e\u0623\u0652\u062e\u064f\u0630\u064f\u0648\u0646\u064e\u0647\u064f \u0628\u064f\u0647\u0652\u062a\u064e\u0627\u0646\u064b\u0627 \u0648\u064e\u0625\u0650\u062b\u0652\u0645\u064b\u0627 \u0645\u064f\u0628\u0650\u064a\u0646\u064b\u0627", "sura": "An-Nisa'", "id": 20}, "text_no_highlight": "\u064a\u0627 \u0623\u064a\u0647\u0627 \u0627\u0644\u0630\u064a\u0646 \u0622\u0645\u0646\u0648\u0627 \u0644\u0627 \u064a\u062d\u0644 \u0644\u0643\u0645 \u0623\u0646 \u062a\u0631\u062b\u0648\u0627 \u0627\u0644\u0646\u0633\u0627\u0621 \u0643\u0631\u0647\u0627 \u0648\u0644\u0627 \u062a\u0639\u0636\u0644\u0648\u0647\u0646 \u0644\u062a\u0630\u0647\u0628\u0648\u0627 \u0628\u0628\u0639\u0636 \u0645\u0627 \u0622\u062a\u064a\u062a\u0645\u0648\u0647\u0646 \u0625\u0644\u0627 \u0623\u0646 \u064a\u0623\u062a\u064a\u0646 \u0628\u0641\u0627\u062d\u0634\u0629 \u0645\u0628\u064a\u0646\u0629 \u0648\u0639\u0627\u0634\u0631\u0648\u0647\u0646 \u0628\u0627\u0644\u0645\u0639\u0631\u0648\u0641 \u0641\u0625\u0646 \u0643\u0631\u0647\u062a\u0645\u0648\u0647\u0646 \u0641\u0639\u0633\u0649 \u0623\u0646 \u062a\u0643\u0631\u0647\u0648\u0627 \u0634\u064a\u0626\u0627 \u0648\u064a\u062c\u0639\u0644 \u0627\u0644\u0644\u0647 \u0641\u064a\u0647 \u062e\u064a\u0631\u0627 \u0643\u062b\u064a\u0631\u0627", "prev_aya": {"sura_arabic": "\u0627\u0644\u0646\u0633\u0627\u0621", "text": "\u0648\u064e\u0644\u064e\u064a\u0652\u0633\u064e\u062a\u0650 \u0627\u0644\u062a\u0651\u064e\u0648\u0652\u0628\u064e\u0629\u064f \u0644\u0650\u0644\u0651\u064e\u0630\u0650\u064a\u0646\u064e \u064a\u064e\u0639\u0652\u0645\u064e\u0644\u064f\u0648\u0646\u064e \u0627\u0644\u0633\u0651\u064e\u064a\u0651\u0650\u0626\u064e\u0627\u062a\u0650 \u062d\u064e\u062a\u0651\u064e\u0649 \u0625\u0650\u0630\u064e\u0627 \u062d\u064e\u0636\u064e\u0631\u064e \u0623\u064e\u062d\u064e\u062f\u064e\u0647\u064f\u0645\u064f \u0627\u0644\u0652\u0645\u064e\u0648\u0652\u062a\u064f \u0642\u064e\u0627\u0644\u064e \u0625\u0650\u0646\
u0651\u0650\u064a \u062a\u064f\u0628\u0652\u062a\u064f \u0627\u0644\u0652\u0622\u0646\u064e \u0648\u064e\u0644\u064e\u0627 \u0627\u0644\u0651\u064e\u0630\u0650\u064a\u0646\u064e \u064a\u064e\u0645\u064f\u0648\u062a\u064f\u0648\u0646\u064e \u0648\u064e\u0647\u064f\u0645\u0652 \u0643\u064f\u0641\u0651\u064e\u0627\u0631\u064c \u0623\u064f\u0648\u0644\u064e\u0626\u0650\u0643\u064e \u0623\u064e\u0639\u0652\u062a\u064e\u062f\u0652\u0646\u064e\u0627 \u0644\u064e\u0647\u064f\u0645\u0652 \u0639\u064e\u0630\u064e\u0627\u0628\u064b\u0627 \u0623\u064e\u0644\u0650\u064a\u0645\u064b\u0627", "sura": "An-Nisa'", "id": 18}, "recitation": "https://www.everyayah.com/data/Abdul_Basit_Murattal_64kbps/004019.mp3", "translation": null, "text": "\u064a\u064e\u0627 \u0623\u064e\u064a\u0651\u064f\u0647\u064e\u0627 \u0627\u0644\u0651\u064e\u0630\u0650\u064a\u0646\u064e \u0622\u0645\u064e\u0646\u064f\u0648\u0627 \u0644\u064e\u0627 \u064a\u064e\u062d\u0650\u0644\u0651\u064f \u0644\u064e\u0643\u064f\u0645\u0652 \u0623\u064e\u0646\u0652 \u062a\u064e\u0631\u0650\u062b\u064f\u0648\u0627 \u0627\u0644\u0646\u0651\u0650\u0633\u064e\u0627\u0621\u064e \u0643\u064e\u0631\u0652\u0647\u064b\u0627 \u0648\u064e\u0644\u064e\u0627 \u062a\u064e\u0639\u0652\u0636\u064f\u0644\u064f\u0648\u0647\u064f\u0646\u0651\u064e \u0644\u0650\u062a\u064e\u0630\u0652\u0647\u064e\u0628\u064f\u0648\u0627 \u0628\u0650\u0628\u064e\u0639\u0652\u0636\u0650 \u0645\u064e\u0627 \u0622\u062a\u064e\u064a\u0652\u062a\u064f\u0645\u064f\u0648\u0647\u064f\u0646\u0651\u064e \u0625\u0650\u0644\u0651\u064e\u0627 \u0623\u064e\u0646\u0652 \u064a\u064e\u0623\u0652\u062a\u0650\u064a\u0646\u064e \u0628\u0650\u0641\u064e\u0627\u062d\u0650\u0634\u064e\u0629\u064d \u0645\u064f\u0628\u064e\u064a\u0651\u0650\u0646\u064e\u0629\u064d \u0648\u064e\u0639\u064e\u0627\u0634\u0650\u0631\u064f\u0648\u0647\u064f\u0646\u0651\u064e \u0628\u0650\u0627\u0644\u0652\u0645\u064e\u0639\u0652\u0631\u064f\u0648\u0641\u0650 \u0641\u064e\u0625\u0650\u0646\u0652 <span class=\"match term0\">\u0643\u064e\u0631\u0650\u0647\u0652\u062a\u064f\u0645\u064f\u0648\u0647\u064f\u0646\u0651\u064e</span> \u0641\u064e\u0639\u064e\u0633\u064e\u0649 \u0623\u064e\u0646\u0652 <span class=\"match term1\">\u062a\u064e\u0643\u0652\u0631\u064e\u0647\u064f\u0648\u0627</span> \u0634\u064e\u064a\u0652\u0626\u064b\u0627 \u0648\u064e\u064a\u064e\u062c\u0652\u0639\u064e\u0644\u064e \u0627\u0644\u0644\u0651\u064e\u0647\u064f \u0641\u0650\u064a\u0647\u0650 \u062e\u064e\u064a\u0652\u0631\u064b\u0627 \u0643\u064e\u062b\u0650\u064a\u0631\u064b\u0627"}, "position": {}, "sajda": {"type": null, "exist": false, "id": null}, "annotations": {}, "sura": {}}, "3": {"stat": {"godnames": 3, "letters": 217, "words": 48}, "identifier": {"sura_name": "An-Nur", "sura_arabic_name": "\u0627\u0644\u0646\u0648\u0631", "aya_id": 33, "sura_id": 24, "gid": 2824}, "theme": {"topic": "\u0627\u0631\u062a\u0643\u0627\u0628 \u0627\u0644\u0641\u0648\u0627\u062d\u0634 \u0648\u0627\u0644\u0632\u0646\u0627 ", "subtopic": null, "chapter": "\u0627\u0644\u0623\u0639\u0645\u0627\u0644 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u062d\u0631\u0645\u0629 "}, "aya": {"id": 33, "next_aya": {"sura_arabic": "\u0627\u0644\u0646\u0648\u0631", "text": "\u0648\u064e\u0644\u064e\u0642\u064e\u062f\u0652 \u0623\u064e\u0646\u0652\u0632\u064e\u0644\u0652\u0646\u064e\u0627 \u0625\u0650\u0644\u064e\u064a\u0652\u0643\u064f\u0645\u0652 \u0622\u064a\u064e\u0627\u062a\u064d \u0645\u064f\u0628\u064e\u064a\u0651\u0650\u0646\u064e\u0627\u062a\u064d \u0648\u064e\u0645\u064e\u062b\u064e\u0644\u064b\u0627 \u0645\u0650\u0646\u064e \u0627\u0644\u0651\u064e\u0630\u0650\u064a\u0646\u064e \u062e\u064e\u0644\u064e\u0648\u0652\u0627 \u0645\u0650\u0646\u0652 \u0642\u064e\u0628\u0652\u0644\u0650\u0643\u064f\u0645\u0652 \u0648\u064e\u0645\u064e\u0648\u0652\u0639\u0650\u0638\u064e\u0629\u064b \u0644\u0650\u0644\u0652\u0645\u064f\u062a\u0651\u064e\u0642\u0650\u064a\u0646\u064e", "sura": "An-Nur", "id": 34}, "text_no_highlight": "\u0648\u0644\u064a\u0633\u062a\u0639\u0641\u0641 \u0627\u0644\u0630\u064a\u0646 \u0644\u0627 \u064a\u062c\u062f\u0648\u0646 \u0646\u0643\u0627\u062d\u0627 \u062d\u062a\u0649 \u064a\u063a\u0646\u064a\u0647\u0645 \u0627\u0644\u0644\u0647 \u0645\u0646 \u0641\u0636\u0644\u0647 \u0648\u0627\u0644\u0630\u064a\u0646 \u064a\u0628\u062a\u063a\u0648\u0646 \u0627\u0644\u0643\u062a\u0627\u0628 \u0645\u0645\u0627 \u0645\u0644\u0643\u062a \u0623\u064a\u0645\u0627\u0646\u0643\u0645 \u0641\u0643\u0627\u062a\u0628\u0648\u0647\u0645 \u0625\u0646 \u0639\u0644\u0645\u062a\u0645 \u0641\u064a\u0647\u0645 \u062e\u064a\u0631\u0627 \u0648\u0622\u062a\u0648\u0647\u0645 \u0645\u0646 \u0645\u0627\u0644 \u0627\u0644\u0644\u0647 \u0627\u0644\u0630\u064a \u0622\u062a\u0627\u0643\u0645 \u0648\u0644\u0627 \u062a\u0643\u0631\u0647\u0648\u0627 \u0641\u062a\u064a\u0627\u062a\u0643\u0645 \u0639\u0644\u0649 \u0627\u0644\u0628\u063a\u0627\u0621 \u0625\u0646 \u0623\u0631\u062f\u0646 \u062a\u062d\u0635\u0646\u0627 \u0644\u062a\u0628\u062a\u063a\u0648\u0627 \u0639\u0631\u0636 \u0627\u0644\u062d\u064a\u0627\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u062f\u0646\u064a\u0627 \u0648\u0645\u0646 \u064a\u0643\u0631\u0647\u0647\u0646 \u0641\u0625\u0646 \u0627\u0644\u0644\u0647 \u0645\u0646 \u0628\u0639\u062f \u0625\u0643\u0631\u0627\u0647\u0647\u0646 \u063a\u0641\u0648\u0631 \u0631\u062d\u064a\u0645", "prev_aya": {"sura_arabic": "\u0627\u0644\u0646\u0648\u0631", "text": "\u0648\u064e\u0623\u064e\u0646\u0652\u0643\u0650\u062d\u064f\u0648\u0627 \u0627\u0644\u0652\u0623\u064e\u064a\u064e\u0627\u0645\u064e\u0649 \u0645\u0650\u0646\u0652\u0643\u064f\u0645\u0652 \u0648\u064e\u0627\u0644\u0635\u0651\u064e\u0627\u0644\u0650\u062d\u0650\u064a\u0646\u064e \u0645\u0650\u0646\u0652 \u0639\u0650\u0628\u064e\u0627\u062f\u0650\u0643\u064f\u0645\u0652 \u0648\u064e\u0625\u0650\u0645\u064e\u0627\u0626\u0650\u0643\u064f\u0645\u0652 \u0625\u0650\u0646\u0652 \u064a\u064e\u0643\u064f\u0648\u0646\u064f\u0648\u0627 \u0641\u064f\u0642\u064e\u0631\u064e\u0627\u0621\u064e \u064a\u064f\u063a\u0652\u0646\u0650\u0647\u0650\u0645\u064f \u0627\u0644\u0644\u0651\u064e\u0647\u064f \u0645\u0650\u0646\u0652 \u0641\u064e\u0636\u0652\u0644\u0650\u0647\u0650 \u0648\u064e\u0627\u0644\u0644\u0651\u064e\u0647\u064f \u0648\u064e\u0627\u0633\u0650\u0639\u064c \u0639\u064e\u0644\u0650\u064a\u0645\u064c", "sura": "An-Nur", "id": 32}, "recitation": "https://www.everyayah.com/data/Abdul_Basit_Murattal_64kbps/024033.mp3", "translation": null, "text": "\u0648\u064e\u0644\u0652\u064a\u064e\u0633\u0652\u062a\u064e\u0639\u0652\u0641\u0650\u0641\u0650 \u0627\u0644\u0651\u064e\u0630\u0650\u064a\u0646\u064e \u0644\u064e\u0627 \u064a\u064e\u062c\u0650\u062f\u064f\u0648\u0646\u064e \u0646\u0650\u0643\u064e\u0627\u062d\u064b\u0627 \u062d\u064e\u062a\u0651\u064e\u0649 \u064a\u064f\u063a\u0652\u0646\u0650\u064a\u064e\u0647\u064f\u0645\u064f \u0627\u0644\u0644\u0651\u064e\u0647\u064f \u0645\u0650\u0646\u0652 \u0641\u064e\u0636\u0652\u0644\u0650\u0647\u0650 \u0648\u064e\u0627\u0644\u0651\u064e\u0630\u0650\u064a\u0646\u064e \u064a\u064e\u0628\u0652\u062a\u064e\u063a\u064f\u0648\u0646\u064e \u0627\u0644\u0652\u0643\u0650\u062a\u064e\u0627\u0628\u064e \u0645\u0650\u0645\u0651\u064e\u0627 \u0645\u064e\u0644\u064e\u0643\u064e\u062a\u0652 \u0623\u064e\u064a\u0652\u0645\u064e\u0627\u0646\u064f\u0643\u064f\u0645\u0652 \u0641\u064e\u0643\u064e\u0627\u062a\u0650\u0628\u064f\u0648\u0647\u064f\u0645\u0652 \u0625\u0650\u0646\u0652 \u0639\u064e\u0644\u0650\u0645\u0652\u062a\u064f\u0645\u0652 \u0641\u0650\u064a\u0647\u0650\u0645\u0652 \u062e\u064e\u064a\u0652\u0631\u064b\u0627 \u0648\u064e\u0622\u062a\u064f\u0648\u0647\u064f\u0645\u0652 \u0645\u0650\u0646\u0652 \u0645\u064e\u0627\u0644\u0650 \u0627\u0644\u0644\u0651\u064e\u0647\u0650 \u0627\u0644\u0651\u064e\u0630\u0650\u064a \u0622\u062a\u064e\u0627\u0643\u064f\u0645\u0652 \u0648\u064e\u0644\u064e\u0627 <span class=\"match term0\">\u062a\u064f\u0643\u0652\u0631\u0650\u0647\u064f\u0648\u0627</span> \u0641\u064e\u062a\u064e\u064a\u064e\u0627\u062a\u0650\u0643\u064f\u0645\u0652 \u0639\u064e\u0644\u064e\u0649 \u0627\u0644\u0652\u0628\u0650\u063a\u064e\u0627\u0621\u0650 \u0625\u0650\u0646\u0652 \u0623\u064e\u0631\u064e\u062f\u0652\u0646\u064e \u062a\u064e\u062d\u064e\u0635\u0651\u064f\u0646\u064b\u0627 \u0644\u0650\u062a\u064e\u0628\u0652\u062a\u064e\u063a\u064f\u0648\u0627 \u0639\u064e\u0631\u064e\u0636\u064e \u0627\u0644\u0652\u062d\u064e\u064a\u064e\u0627\u0629\u0650 \u0627\u0644\u062f\u0651\u064f\u0646\u0652\u064a\u064e\u0627 \u0648\u064e\u0645\u064e\u0646\u0652 <span class=\"match term1\">\u064a\u064f\u0643\u0652\u0631\u0650\u0647\u0652\u0647\u064f\u0646\u0651\u064e</span> \u0641\u064e\u0625\u0650\u0646\u0651\u064e \u0627\u0644\u0644\u0651\u064e\u0647\u064e \u0645\u0650\u0646\u0652 \u0628\u064e\u0639\u0652\u062f\u0650 \u0625\u0650\u0643\u0652\u0631\u064e\u0627\u0647\u0650\u0647\u0650\u0646\u0651\u064e \u063a\u064e\u0641\u064f\u0648\u0631\u064c \u0631\u064e\u062d\u0650\u064a\u0645\u064c"}, "position": {}, "sajda": {"type": null, "exist": false, "id": null}, "annotations": {}, "sura": {}}, "4": {"stat": {"godnames": 1, "letters": 35, "words": 8}, "identifier": {"sura_name": "Muhammad", "sura_arabic_name": "\u0645\u062d\u0645\u062f", "aya_id": 9, "sura_id": 47, "gid": 4554}, "theme": {"topic": "\u0627\u0644\u0643\u0641\u0631 \u0648\u0627\u0644\u0643\u0627\u0641\u0631\u0648\u0646", "subtopic": "\u0627\u0644\u0643\u0641\u0631 \u064a\u062d\u0628\u0637 \u0627\u0644\u0639\u0645\u0644", "chapter": "\u062a\u0642\u0631\u064a\u0631 \u0627\u0644\u062a\u0648\u062d\u064a\u062f \u0648\u0628\u0637\u0644\u0627\u0646 \u0627\u0644\u0634\u0631\u0643 \u0648\u0627\u0644\u0643\u0641\u0631 "}, "aya": {"id": 9, "next_aya": {"sura_arabic": "\u0645\u062d\u0645\u062f", "text": "\u0623\u064e\u0641\u064e\u0644\u064e\u0645\u0652 \u064a\u064e\u0633\u0650\u064a\u0631\u064f\u0648\u0627 \u0641\u0650\u064a \u0627\u0644\u0652\u0623\u064e\u0631\u0652\u0636\u0650 \u0641\u064e\u064a\u064e\u0646\u0652\u0638\u064f\u0631\u064f\u0648\u0627 \u0643\u064e\u064a\u0652\
u0641\u064e \u0643\u064e\u0627\u0646\u064e \u0639\u064e\u0627\u0642\u0650\u0628\u064e\u0629\u064f \u0627\u0644\u0651\u064e\u0630\u0650\u064a\u0646\u064e \u0645\u0650\u0646\u0652 \u0642\u064e\u0628\u0652\u0644\u0650\u0647\u0650\u0645\u0652 \u062f\u064e\u0645\u0651\u064e\u0631\u064e \u0627\u0644\u0644\u0651\u064e\u0647\u064f \u0639\u064e\u0644\u064e\u064a\u0652\u0647\u0650\u0645\u0652 \u0648\u064e\u0644\u0650\u0644\u0652\u0643\u064e\u0627\u0641\u0650\u0631\u0650\u064a\u0646\u064e \u0623\u064e\u0645\u0652\u062b\u064e\u0627\u0644\u064f\u0647\u064e\u0627", "sura": "Muhammad", "id": 10}, "text_no_highlight": "\u0630\u0644\u0643 \u0628\u0623\u0646\u0647\u0645 \u0643\u0631\u0647\u0648\u0627 \u0645\u0627 \u0623\u0646\u0632\u0644 \u0627\u0644\u0644\u0647 \u0641\u0623\u062d\u0628\u0637 \u0623\u0639\u0645\u0627\u0644\u0647\u0645", "prev_aya": {"sura_arabic": "\u0645\u062d\u0645\u062f", "text": "\u0648\u064e\u0627\u0644\u0651\u064e\u0630\u0650\u064a\u0646\u064e \u0643\u064e\u0641\u064e\u0631\u064f\u0648\u0627 \u0641\u064e\u062a\u064e\u0639\u0652\u0633\u064b\u0627 \u0644\u064e\u0647\u064f\u0645\u0652 \u0648\u064e\u0623\u064e\u0636\u064e\u0644\u0651\u064e \u0623\u064e\u0639\u0652\u0645\u064e\u0627\u0644\u064e\u0647\u064f\u0645\u0652", "sura": "Muhammad", "id": 8}, "recitation": "https://www.everyayah.com/data/Abdul_Basit_Murattal_64kbps/047009.mp3", "translation": null, "text": "\u0630\u064e\u0644\u0650\u0643\u064e \u0628\u0650\u0623\u064e\u0646\u0651\u064e\u0647\u064f\u0645\u0652 <span class=\"match term0\">\u0643\u064e\u0631\u0650\u0647\u064f\u0648\u0627</span> \u0645\u064e\u0627 \u0623\u064e\u0646\u0652\u0632\u064e\u0644\u064e \u0627\u0644\u0644\u0651\u064e\u0647\u064f \u0641\u064e\u0623\u064e\u062d\u0652\u0628\u064e\u0637\u064e \u0623\u064e\u0639\u0652\u0645\u064e\u0627\u0644\u064e\u0647\u064f\u0645\u0652"}, "position": {}, "sajda": {"type": null, "exist": false, "id": null}, "annotations": {}, "sura": {}}, "5": {"stat": {"godnames": 1, "letters": 48, "words": 10}, "identifier": {"sura_name": "Muhammad", "sura_arabic_name": "\u0645\u062d\u0645\u062f", "aya_id": 28, "sura_id": 47, "gid": 4573}, "theme": {"topic": "\u0645\u0644\u0627\u0626\u0643\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0648\u062a", "subtopic": null, "chapter": "\u0623\u0631\u0643\u0627\u0646 \u0627\u0644\u0625\u064a\u0645\u0627\u0646"}, "aya": {"id": 28, "next_aya": {"sura_arabic": "\u0645\u062d\u0645\u062f", "text": "\u0623\u064e\u0645\u0652 \u062d\u064e\u0633\u0650\u0628\u064e \u0627\u0644\u0651\u064e\u0630\u0650\u064a\u0646\u064e \u0641\u0650\u064a \u0642\u064f\u0644\u064f\u0648\u0628\u0650\u0647\u0650\u0645\u0652 \u0645\u064e\u0631\u064e\u0636\u064c \u0623\u064e\u0646\u0652 \u0644\u064e\u0646\u0652 \u064a\u064f\u062e\u0652\u0631\u0650\u062c\u064e \u0627\u0644\u0644\u0651\u064e\u0647\u064f \u0623\u064e\u0636\u0652\u063a\u064e\u0627\u0646\u064e\u0647\u064f\u0645\u0652", "sura": "Muhammad", "id": 29}, "text_no_highlight": "\u0630\u0644\u0643 \u0628\u0623\u0646\u0647\u0645 \u0627\u062a\u0628\u0639\u0648\u0627 \u0645\u0627 \u0623\u0633\u062e\u0637 \u0627\u0644\u0644\u0647 \u0648\u0643\u0631\u0647\u0648\u0627 \u0631\u0636\u0648\u0627\u0646\u0647 \u0641\u0623\u062d\u0628\u0637 \u0623\u0639\u0645\u0627\u0644\u0647\u0645", "prev_aya": {"sura_arabic": "\u0645\u062d\u0645\u062f", "text": "\u0641\u064e\u0643\u064e\u064a\u0652\u0641\u064e \u0625\u0650\u0630\u064e\u0627 \u062a\u064e\u0648\u064e\u0641\u0651\u064e\u062a\u0652\u0647\u064f\u0645\u064f \u0627\u0644\u0652\u0645\u064e\u0644\u064e\u0627\u0626\u0650\u0643\u064e\u0629\u064f \u064a\u064e\u0636\u0652\u0631\u0650\u0628\u064f\u0648\u0646\u064e \u0648\u064f\u062c\u064f\u0648\u0647\u064e\u0647\u064f\u0645\u0652 \u0648\u064e\u0623\u064e\u062f\u0652\u0628\u064e\u0627\u0631\u064e\u0647\u064f\u0645\u0652", "sura": "Muhammad", "id": 27}, "recitation": "https://www.everyayah.com/data/Abdul_Basit_Murattal_64kbps/047028.mp3", "translation": null, "text": "\u0630\u064e\u0644\u0650\u0643\u064e \u0628\u0650\u0623\u064e\u0646\u0651\u064e\u0647\u064f\u0645\u064f \u0627\u062a\u0651\u064e\u0628\u064e\u0639\u064f\u0648\u0627 \u0645\u064e\u0627 \u0623\u064e\u0633\u0652\u062e\u064e\u0637\u064e \u0627\u0644\u0644\u0651\u064e\u0647\u064e <span class=\"match term0\">\u0648\u064e\u0643\u064e\u0631\u0650\u0647\u064f\u0648\u0627</span> \u0631\u0650\u0636\u0652\u0648\u064e\u0627\u0646\u064e\u0647\u064f \u0641\u064e\u0623\u064e\u062d\u0652\u0628\u064e\u0637\u064e \u0623\u064e\u0639\u0652\u0645\u064e\u0627\u0644\u064e\u0647\u064f\u0645\u0652"}, "position": {}, "sajda": {"type": null, "exist": false, "id": null}, "annotations": {}, "sura": {}}, "10": {"stat": {"godnames": 1, "letters": 37, "words": 8}, "identifier": {"sura_name": "Ghafir", "sura_arabic_name": "\u063a\u0627\u0641\u0631", "aya_id": 14, "sura_id": 40, "gid": 4147}, "theme": {"topic": "\u0625\u062e\u0644\u0627\u0635 \u0627\u0644\u0639\u0645\u0644 \u0644\u0644\u0647 ", "subtopic": null, "chapter": "\u0634\u0639\u0628 \u0627\u0644\u0625\u064a\u0645\u0627\u0646 "}, "aya": {"id": 14, "next_aya": {"sura_arabic": "\u063a\u0627\u0641\u0631", "text": "\u0631\u064e\u0641\u0650\u064a\u0639\u064f \u0627\u0644\u062f\u0651\u064e\u0631\u064e\u062c\u064e\u0627\u062a\u0650 \u0630\u064f\u0648 \u0627\u0644\u0652\u0639\u064e\u0631\u0652\u0634\u0650 \u064a\u064f\u0644\u0652\u0642\u0650\u064a \u0627\u0644\u0631\u0651\u064f\u0648\u062d\u064e \u0645\u0650\u0646\u0652 \u0623\u064e\u0645\u0652\u0631\u0650\u0647\u0650 \u0639\u064e\u0644\u064e\u0649 \u0645\u064e\u0646\u0652 \u064a\u064e\u0634\u064e\u0627\u0621\u064f \u0645\u0650\u0646\u0652 \u0639\u0650\u0628\u064e\u0627\u062f\u0650\u0647\u0650 \u0644\u0650\u064a\u064f\u0646\u0652\u0630\u0650\u0631\u064e \u064a\u064e\u0648\u0652\u0645\u064e \u0627\u0644\u062a\u0651\u064e\u0644\u064e\u0627\u0642\u0650", "sura": "Ghafir", "id": 15}, "text_no_highlight": "\u0641\u0627\u062f\u0639\u0648\u0627 \u0627\u0644\u0644\u0647 \u0645\u062e\u0644\u0635\u064a\u0646 \u0644\u0647 \u0627\u0644\u062f\u064a\u0646 \u0648\u0644\u0648 \u0643\u0631\u0647 \u0627\u0644\u0643\u0627\u0641\u0631\u0648\u0646", "prev_aya": {"sura_arabic": "\u063a\u0627\u0641\u0631", "text": "\u0647\u064f\u0648\u064e \u0627\u0644\u0651\u064e\u0630\u0650\u064a \u064a\u064f\u0631\u0650\u064a\u0643\u064f\u0645\u0652 \u0622\u064a\u064e\u0627\u062a\u0650\u0647\u0650 \u0648\u064e\u064a\u064f\u0646\u064e\u0632\u0651\u0650\u0644\u064f \u0644\u064e\u0643\u064f\u0645\u0652 \u0645\u0650\u0646\u064e \u0627\u0644\u0633\u0651\u064e\u0645\u064e\u0627\u0621\u0650 \u0631\u0650\u0632\u0652\u0642\u064b\u0627 \u0648\u064e\u0645\u064e\u0627 \u064a\u064e\u062a\u064e\u0630\u064e\u0643\u0651\u064e\u0631\u064f \u0625\u0650\u0644\u0651\u064e\u0627 \u0645\u064e\
u0646\u0652 \u064a\u064f\u0646\u0650\u064a\u0628\u064f", "sura": "Ghafir", "id": 13}, "recitation": "https://www.everyayah.com/data/Abdul_Basit_Murattal_64kbps/040014.mp3", "translation": null, "text": "\u0641\u064e\u0627\u062f\u0652\u0639\u064f\u0648\u0627 \u0627\u0644\u0644\u0651\u064e\u0647\u064e \u0645\u064f\u062e\u0652\u0644\u0650\u0635\u0650\u064a\u0646\u064e \u0644\u064e\u0647\u064f \u0627\u0644\u062f\u0651\u0650\u064a\u0646\u064e \u0648\u064e\u0644\u064e\u0648\u0652 <span class=\"match term0\">\u0643\u064e\u0631\u0650\u0647\u064e</span> \u0627\u0644\u0652\u0643\u064e\u0627\u0641\u0650\u0631\u064f\u0648\u0646\u064e"}, "position": {}, "sajda": {"type": null, "exist": false, "id": null}, "annotations": {}, "sura": {}}}, "translation_info": {}, "words": {"individual": {}}, "runtime": 0.14392}]
```

It gives the following error:

```
Error: Parse error on line 1:
...627\u0621", "text": "\u0648\u064e\u0644\
-----------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'undefined'
```

I do not understand what the issue is. I just downloaded this data from a web API.

Some other Q&A said maybe the " is wrong, but they all look the same to me in the file.

Answer (score 0):

**this is correct now**

```
[{"interval": {"page": 1, "start": 1, "total": 21, "end": 10, "nb_pages": 3}, "ayas": {"1": {"stat": {"godnames": 1, "letters": 93, "words": 25}, "identifier": {"sura_name": "Al-Baqarah", "sura_arabic_name": "\u0627\u0644\u0628\u0642\u0631\u0629", "aya_id": 216, "sura_id": 2, "gid": 223}, "theme": {"topic": "\u0641\u0636\u0644 \u0627\u0644\u062c\u0647\u0627\u062f \u0648\u0627\u0644\u062f\u0639\u0648\u0629 \u0625\u0644\u064a\u0647", "subtopic": null, "chapter": "\u0627\u0644\u062c\u0647\u0627\u062f \u0641\u064a \u0627\u0644\u0625\u0633\u0644\u0627\u0645 "}, "aya": {"id": 216, "next_aya": {"sura_arabic": "\u0627\u0644\u0628\u0642\u0631\u0629", "text": "\u064a\u064e\u0633\u0652\u0623\u064e\u0644\u064f\u0648\u0646\u064e\u0643\u064e \u0639\u064e\u0646\u0650 \u0627\u0644\u0634\u0651\u064e\u0647\u0652\u0631\u0650 \u0627\u0644\u0652\u062d\u064e\u0631\u064e\u0627\u0645\u0650 \u0642\u0650\u062a\u064e\u0627\u0644\u064d \u0641\u0650\u064a\u0647\u0650 \u0642\u064f\u0644\u0652 \u0642\u0650\u062a\u064e\u0627\u0644\u064c \u0641\u0650\u064a\u0647\u0650 \u0643\u064e\u0628\u0650\u064a\u0631\u064c \u0648\u064e\u0635\u064e\u062f\u0651\u064c \u0639\u064e\u0646\u0652 \u0633\u064e\u0628\u0650\u064a\u0644\u0650 \u0627\u0644\u0644\u0651\u064e\u0647\u0650 \u0648\u064e\u0643\u064f\u0641\u0652\u0631\u064c \u0628\u0650\u0647\u0650 \u0648\u064e\u0627\u0644\u0652\u0645\u064e\u0633\u0652\u062c\u0650\u062f\u0650 \u0627\u0644\u0652\u062d\u064e\u0631\u064e\u0627\u0645\u0650 \u0648\u064e\u0625\u0650\u062e\u0652\u0631\u064e\u0627\u062c\u064f \u0623\u064e\u0647\u0652\u0644\u0650\u0647\u0650 \u0645\u0650\u0646\u0652\u0647\u064f \u0623\u064e\u0643\u0652\u0628\u064e\u0631\u064f \u0639\u0650\u0646\u0652\u062f\u064e \u0627\u0644\u0644\u0651\u064e\u0647\u0650 \u0648\u064e\u0627\u0644\u0652\u0641\u0650\u062a\u0652\u0646\u064e\u0629\u064f \u0623\u064e\u0643\u0652\u0628\u064e\u0631\u064f \u0645\u0650\u0646\u064e \u0627\u0644\u0652\u0642\u064e\u062a\u0652\u0644\u0650 \u0648\u064e\u0644\u064e\u0627 \u064a\u064e\u0632\u064e\u0627\u0644\u064f\u0648\u0646\u064e \u064a\u064f\u0642\u064e\u0627\u062a\u0650\u0644\u064f\u0648\u0646\u064e\u0643\u064f\u0645\u0652 \u062d\u064e\u062a\u0651\u064e\u0649 \u064a\u064e\u0631\u064f\u062f\u0651\u064f\u0648\u0643\u064f\u0645\u0652 \u0639\u064e\u0646\u0652 \u062f\u0650\u064a\u0646\u0650\u0643\u064f\u0645\u0652 \u0625\u0650\u0646\u0650 \u0627\u0633\u0652\u062a\u064e\u0637\u064e\u0627\u0639\u064f\u0648\u0627 \u0648\u064e\u0645\u064e\u0646\u0652 \u064a\u064e\u0631\u0652\u062a\u064e\u062f\u0650\u062f\u0652 \u0645\u0650\u0646\u0652\u0643\u064f\u0645\u0652 \u0639\u064e\u0646\u0652 \u062f\u0650\u064a\u0646\u0650\u0647\u0650 \u0641\u064e\u064a\u064e\u0645\u064f\u062a\u0652 \u0648\u064e\u0647\u064f\u0648\u064e \u0643\u064e\u0627\u0641\u0650\u0631\u064c \u0641\u064e\u0623\u064f\u0648\u0644\u064e\u0626\u0650\u0643\u064e \u062d\u064e\u0628\u0650\u0637\u064e\u062a\u0652 \u0623\u064e\u0639\u0652\u0645\u064e\u0627\u0644\u064f\u0647\u064f\u0645\u0652 \u0641\u0650\u064a \u0627\u0644\u062f\u0651\u064f\u0646\u0652\u064a\u064e\u0627 \u0648\u064e\u0627\u0644\u0652\u0622\u062e\u0650\u0631\u064e\u0629\u0650 \u0648\u064e\u0623\u064f\u0648\u0644\u064e\u0626\u0650\u0643\u064e \u0623\u064e\u0635\u0652\u062d\u064e\u0627\u0628\u064f \u0627\u0644\u0646\u0651\u064e\u0627\u0631\u0650 \u0647\u064f\u0645\u0652 \u0641\u0650\u064a\u0647\u064e\u0627 \u062e\u064e\u0627\u0644\u0650\u062f\u064f\u0648\u0646\u064e", "sura": "Al-Baqarah", "id": 217}, "text_no_highlight": "\u0643\u062a\u0628 \u0639\u0644\u064a\u0643\u0645 \u0627\u0644\u0642\u062a\u0627\u0644 \u0648\u0647\u0648 \u0643\u0631\u0647 \u0644\u0643\u0645 \u0648\u0639\u0633\u0649 \u0623\u0646 \u062a\u0643\u0631\u0647\u0648\u0627 \u0634\u064a\u0626\u0627 \u0648\u0647\u0648 \u062e\u064a\u0631 \u0644\u0643\u0645 \u0648\u0639\u0633\u0649 \u0623\u0646 \u062a\u062d\u0628\u0648\u0627 \u0634\u064a\u0626\u0627 \u0648\u0647\u0648 \u0634\u0631 \u0644\u0643\u0645 \u0648\u0627\u0644\u0644\u0647 \u064a\u0639\u0644\u0645 \u0648\u0623\u0646\u062a\u0645 \u0644\u0627 \u062a\u0639\u0644\u0645\u0648\u0646", "prev_aya": {"sura_arabic": "\u0627\u0644\u0628\u0642\u0631\u0629", "text": "\u064a\u064e\u0633\u0652\u0623\u064e\u0644\u064f\u0648\u0646\u064e\u0643\u064e \u0645\u064e\u0627\u0630\u064e\u0627 \u064a\u064f\u0646\u0652\u0641\u0650\u0642\u064f\u0648\u0646\u064e \u0642\u064f\u0644\u0652 \u0645\u064e\u0627 \u0623\u064e\u0646\u0652\u0641\u064e\u0642\u0652\u062a\u064f\u0645\u0652 \u0645\u0650\u0646\u0652 \u062e\u064e\u064a\u0652\u0631\u064d \u0641\u064e\u0644\u0650\u0644\u0652\u0648\u064e\u0627\u0644\u0650\u062f\u064e\u064a\u0652\u0646\u0650 \u0648\u064e\u0627\u0644\u0652\u0623\u064e\u0642\u0652\u0631\u064e\u0628\u0650\u064a\u0646\u064e \u0648\u064e\u0627\u0644\u0652\u064a\u064e\u062a\u064e\u0627\u0645\u064e\u0649 \u0648\u064e\u0627\u0644\u0652\u0645\u064e\u0633\u064e\u0627\u0643\u0650\u064a\u0646\u0650 \u0648\u064e\u0627\u0628\u0652\u0646\u0650 \u0627\u0644\u0633\u0651\u064e\u0628\u0650\u064a\u0644\u0650 \u0648\u064e\u0645\u064e\u0627 \u062a\u064e\u0641\u0652\u0639\u064e\u0644\u064f\u0648\u0627 \u0645\u0650\u0646\u0652 \u062e\u064e\u064a\u0652\u0631\u064d \u0641\u064e\u0625\u0650\u0646\u0651\u064e \u0627\u0644\u0644\u0651\u064e\u0647\u064e \u0628\u0650\u0647\u0650 \u0639\u064e\u0644\u0650\u064a\u0645\u064c", "sura": "Al-Baqarah", "id": 215}, "recitation": "https://www.everyayah.com/data/Abdul_Basit_Murattal_64kbps/002216.mp3", "translation": null, "text": "\u0643\u064f\u062a\u0650\u0628\u064e \u0639\u064e\u0644\u064e\u064a\u0652\u0643\u064f\u0645\u064f \u0627\u0644\u0652\u0642\u0650\u062a\u064e\u0627\u0644\u064f \u0648\u064e\u0647\u064f\u0648\u064e <span class=\"match term0\">\u0643\u064f\u0631\u0652\u0647\u064c</span> \u0644\u064e\u0643\u064f\u0645\u0652 \u0648\u064e\u0639\u064e\u0633\u064e\u0649 \u0623\u064e\u0646\u0652 <span class=\"match term1\">\u062a\u064e\u0643\u0652\u0631\u064e\u0647\u064f\u0648\u0627</span> \u0634\u064e\u064a\u0652\u0626\u064b\u0627 \u0648\u064e\u0647\u064f\u0648\u064e \u062e\u064e\u064a\u0652\u0631\u064c \u0644\u064e\u0643\u064f\u0645\u0652 \u0648\u064e\u0639\u064e\u0633\u064e\u0649 \u0623\u064e\u0646\u0652 \u062a\u064f\u062d\u0650\u0628\u0651\u064f\u0648\u0627 \u0634\u064e\u064a\u0652\u0626\u064b\u0627 \u0648\u064e\u0647\u064f\u0648\u064e \u0634\u064e\u0631\u0651\u064c \u0644\u064e\u0643\u064f\u0645\u0652 \u0648\u064e\u0627\u0644\u0644\u0651\u064e\u0647\u064f \u064a\u064e\u0639\u0652\u0644\u064e\u0645\u064f \u0648\u064e\u0623\u064e\u0646\u0652\u062a\u064f\u0645\u0652 \u0644\u064e\u0627 \u062a\u064e\u0639\u0652\u0644\u064e\u0645\u064f\u0648\u0646\u064e"}, "position": {}, "sajda": {"type": null, "exist": false, "id": null}, "annotations": {}, "sura": {}}, "2": {"stat": {"godnames": 1, "letters": 157, "words": 35}, "identifier": {"sura_name": "An-Nisa'", "sura_arabic_name": "\u0627\u0644\u0646\u0633\u0627\u0621", "aya_id": 19, "sura_id": 4, "gid": 512}, "theme": {"topic": "\u0627\u0644\u0645\u0633\u0627\u0648\u0627\u0629 \u0628\u064a\u0646 \u0627\u0644\u0631\u062c\u0644 \u0648\u0627\u0644\u0645\u0631\u0623\u0629 \u0641\u064a \u0627\u0644\u062a\u0643\u0627\u0644\u064a\u0641 \u0648\u0627\u0644\u0648\u0627\u062c\u0628\u0627\u062a ", "subtopic": null, "chapter": "\u062d\u0642\u0648\u0642 \u0627\u0644\u0625\u0646\u0633\u0627\u0646 "}, "aya": {"id": 19, "next_aya": {"sura_arabic": "\u0627\u0644\u0646\u0633\u0627\u0621", "text": "\u0648\u064e\u0625\u0650\u0646\u0652 \u0623\u064e\u0631\u064e\u062f\u0652\u062a\u064f\u0645\u064f \u0627\u0633\u0652\u062a\u0650\u0628\u0652\u062f\u064e\u0627\u0644\u064e \u0632\u064e\u0648\u0652\u062c\u064d \u0645\u064e\u0643\u064e\u0627\u0646\u064e \u0632\u064e\u0648\u0652\u062c\u064d \u0648\u064e\u0622\u062a\u064e\u064a\u0652\u062a\u064f\u0645\u0652 \u0625\u0650\u062d\u0652\u062f\u064e\u0627\u0647\u064f\u0646\u0651\u064e \u0642\u0650\u0646\u0652\u0637\u064e\u0627\u0631\u064b\u0627 \u0641\u064e\u0644\u064e\u0627 \u062a\u064e\u0623\u0652\u062e\u064f\u0630\u064f\u0648\u0627 \u0645\u0650\u0646\u0652\u0647\u064f \u0634\u064e\u064a\u0652\u0626\u064b\u0627 \u0623\u064e\u062a\u064e\u0623\u0652\u062e\u064f\u0630\u064f\u0648\u0646\u064e\u0647\u064f \u0628\u064f\u0647\u0652\u062a\u064e\u0627\u0646\u064b\u0627 \u0648\u064e\u0625\u0650\u062b\u0652\u0645\u064b\u0627 \u0645\u064f\u0628\u0650\u064a\u0646\u064b\u0627", "sura": "An-Nisa'", "id": 20}, "text_no_highlight": "\u064a\u0627 \u0623\u064a\u0647\u0627 \u0627\u0644\u0630\u064a\u0646 \u0622\u0645\u0646\u0648\u0627 \u0644\u0627 \u064a\u062d\u0644 \u0644\u0643\u0645 \u0623\u0646 \u062a\u0631\u062b\u0648\u0627 \u0627\u0644\u0646\u0633\u0627\u0621 \u0643\u0631\u0647\u0627 \u0648\u0644\u0627 \u062a\u0639\u0636\u0644\u0648\u0647\u0646 \u0644\u062a\u0630\u0647\u0628\u0648\u0627 \u0628\u0628\u0639\u0636 \u0645\u0627 \u0622\u062a\u064a\u062a\u0645\u0648\u0647\u0646 \u0625\u0644\u0627 \u0623\u0646 \u064a\u0623\u062a\u064a\u0646 \u0628\u0641\u0627\u062d\u0634\u0629 \u0645\u0628\u064a\u0646\u0629 \u0648\u0639\u0627\u0634\u0631\u0648\u0647\u0646 \u0628\u0627\u0644\u0645\u0639\u0631\u0648\u0641 \u0641\u0625\u0646 \u0643\u0631\u0647\u062a\u0645\u0648\u0647\u0646 \u0641\u0639\u0633\u0649 \u0623\u0646 \u062a\u0643\u0631\u0647\u0648\u0627 \u0634\u064a\u0626\u0627 \u0648\u064a\u062c\u0639\u0644 \u0627\u0644\u0644\u0647 \u0641\u064a\u0647 \u062e\u064a\u0631\u0627 \u0643\u062b\u064a\u0631\u0627", "prev_aya": {"sura_arabic": "\u0627\u0644\u0646\u0633\u0627\u0621", "text": "\u0648\u064e\u0644\u064e\u064a\u0652\u0633\u064e\u062a\u0650 \u0627\u0644\u062a\u0651\u064e\u0648\u0652\u0628\u064e\u0629\u064f \u0644\u0650\u0644\u0651\u064e\u0630\u0650\u064a\u0646\u064e \u064a\u064e\u0639\u0652\u0645\u064e\u0644\u064f\u0648\u0646\u064e \u0627\u0644\u0633\u0651\u064e\u064a\u0651\u0650\u0626\u064e\u0627\u062a\u0650 \u062d\u064e\u062a\u0651\u064e\u0649 \u0625\u0650\u0630\u064e\u0627 \u062d\u064e\u0636\u064e\u0631\u064e \u0623\u064e\u062d\u064e\u062f\u064e\u0647\u064f\u0645\u064f \u0627\u0644\u0652\u0645\u064e\u0648\u0652\u062a\u064f \u0642\u064e\u0627\u0644\u064e \u0625\u0650\u0646\u0651\u0650\u064a \u062a\u064f\u0628\u0652\u062a\u064f \u0627\u0644\u0652\u0622\u0646\u064e \u0648\u064e\u0644\u064e\u0627 \u0627\u0644\u0651\u064e\u0630\u0650\u064a\u0646\u064e \u064a\u064e\u0645\u064f\u0648\u062a\u064f\u0648\u0646\u064e \u0648\u064e\u0647\u064f\u0645\u0652 \u0643\u064f\u0641\u0651\u064e\u0627\u0631\u064c \u0623\u064f\u0648\u0644\u064e\u0626\u0650\u0643\u064e \u0623\u064e\u0639\u0652\u062a\u064e\u062f\u0652\u0646\u064e\u0627 \u0644\u064e\u0647\u064f\u0645\u0652 \u0639\u064e\u0630\u064e\u0627\u0628\u064b\u0627 \u0623\u064e\u0644\u0650\u064a\u0645\u064b\u0627", "sura": "An-Nisa'", "id": 18}, "recitation": "https://www.everyayah.com/data/Abdul_Basit_Murattal_64kbps/004019.mp3", "translation": null, "text": "\u064a\u064e\u0627 \u0623\u064e\u064a\u0651\u064f\u0647\u064e\u0627 \u0627\u0644\u0651\u064e\u0630\u0650\u064a\u0646\u064e \u0622\u0645\u064e\u0646\u064f\u0648\u0627 \u0644\u064e\u0627 \u064a\u064e\u062d\u0650\u0644\u0651\u064f \u0644\u064e\u0643\u064f\u0645\u0652 \u0623\u064e\u0646\u0652 \u062a\u064e\u0631\u0650\u062b\u064f\u0648\u0627 \u0627\u0644\u0646\u0651\u0650\u0633\u064e\u0627\u0621\u064e \u0643\u064e\u0631\u0652\u0647\u064b\u0627 \u0648\u064e\u0644\u064e\u0627 \u062a\u064e\u0639\u0652\u0636\u064f\u0644\u064f\u0648\u0647\u064f\u0646\u0651\u064e \u0644\u0650\u062a\u064e\u0630\u0652\u0647\u064e\u0628\u064f\u0648\u0627 \u0628\u0650\u0628\u064e\u0639\u0652\u0636\u0650 \u0645\u064e\u0627 \u0622\u062a\u064e\u064a\u0652\u062a\u064f\u0645\u064f\u0648\u0647\u064f\u0646\u0651\u064e \u0625\u0650\u0644\u0651\u064e\u0627 \u0623\u064e\u0646\u0652 \u064a\u064e\u0623\u0652\u062a\u0650\u064a\u0646\u064e \u0628\u0650\u0641\u064e\u0627\u062d\u0650\u0634\u064e\u0629\u064d \u0645\u064f\u0628\u064e\u064a\u0651\u0650\u0646\u064e\u0629\u064d \u0648\u064e\u0639\u064e\u0627\u0634\u0650\u0631\u064f\u0648\u0647\u064f\u0646\u0651\u064e \u0628\u0650\u0627\u0644\u0652\u0645\u064e\u0639\u0652\u0631\u064f\u0648\u0641\u0650 \u0641\u064e\u0625\u0650\u0646\u0652 <span class=\"match term0\">\u0643\u064e\u0631\u0650\u0647\u0652\u062a\u064f\u0645\u064f\u0648\u0647\u064f\u0646\u0651\u064e</span> \u0641\u064e\u0639\u064e\u0633\u064e\u0649 \u0623\u064e\u0646\u0652 <span class=\"match term1\">\u062a\u064e\u0643\u0652\u0631\u064e\u0647\u064f\u0648\u0627</span> \u0634\u064e\u064a\u0652\u0626\u064b\u0627 \u0648\u064e\u064a\u064e\u062c\u0652\u0639\u064e\u0644\u064e \u0627\u0644\u0644\u0651\u064e\u0647\u064f \u0641\u0650\u064a\u0647\u0650 \u062e\u064e\u064a\u0652\u0631\u064b\u0627 \u0643\u064e\u062b\u0650\u064a\u0631\u064b\u0627"}, "position": {}, "sajda": {"type": null, "exist": false, "id": null}, "annotations": {}, "sura": {}}, "3": {"stat": {"godnames": 3, "letters": 217, "words": 48}, "identifier": {"sura_name": "An-Nur", "sura_arabic_name": "\u0627\u0644\u0646\u0648\u0631", "aya_id": 33, "sura_id": 24, "gid": 2824}, "theme": {"topic": "\u0627\u0631\u062a\u0643\u0627\u0628 \u0627\u0644\u0641\u0648\u0627\u062d\u0634 \u0648\u0627\u0644\u0632\u0646\u0627 ", "subtopic": null, "chapter": "\u0627\u0644\u0623\u0639\u0645\u0627\u0644 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u062d\u0631\u0645\u0629 "}, "aya": {"id": 33, "next_aya": {"sura_arabic": "\u0627\u0644\u0646\u0648\u0631", "text": "\u0648\u064e\u0644\u064e\u0642\u064e\u062f\u0652 \u0623\u064e\u0646\u0652\u0632\u064e\u0644\u0652\u0646\u064e\u0627 \u0625\u0650\u0644\u064e\u064a\u0652\u0643\u064f\u0645\u0652 \u0622\u064a\u064e\u0627\u062a\u064d \u0645\u064f\u0628\u064e\u064a\u0651\u0650\u0646\u064e\u0627\u062a\u064d \u0648\u064e\u0645\u064e\u062b\u064e\u0644\u064b\u0627 \u0645\u0650\u0646\u064e \u0627\u0644\u0651\u064e\u0630\u0650\u064a\u0646\u064e \u062e\u064e\u0644\u064e\u0648\u0652\u0627 \u0645\u0650\u0646\u0652 \u0642\u064e\u0628\u0652\u0644\u0650\u0643\u064f\u0645\u0652 \u0648\u064e\u0645\u064e\u0648\u0652\u0639\u0650\u0638\u064e\u0629\u064b \u0644\u0650\u0644\u0652\u0645\u064f\u062a\u0651\u064e\u0642\u0650\u064a\u0646\u064e", "sura": "An-Nur", "id": 34}, "text_no_highlight": "\u0648\u0644\u064a\u0633\u062a\u0639\u0641\u0641 \u0627\u0644\u0630\u064a\u0646 \u0644\u0627 \u064a\u062c\u062f\u0648\u0646 \u0646\u0643\u0627\u062d\u0627 \u062d\u062a\u0649 \u064a\u063a\u0646\u064a\u0647\u0645 \u0627\u0644\u0644\u0647 \u0645\u0646 \u0641\u0636\u0644\u0647 \u0648\u0627\u0644\u0630\u064a\u0646 \u064a\u0628\u062a\u063a\u0648\u0646 \u0627\u0644\u0643\u062a\u0627\u0628 \u0645\u0645\u0627 \u0645\u0644\u0643\u062a \u0623\u064a\u0645\u0627\u0646\u0643\u0645 \u0641\u0643\u0627\u062a\u0628\u0648\u0647\u0645 \u0625\u0646 \u0639\u0644\u0645\u062a\u0645 \u0641\u064a\u0647\u0645 \u062e\u064a\u0631\u0627 \u0648\u0622\u062a\u0648\u0647\u0645 \u0645\u0646 \u0645\u0627\u0644 \u0627\u0644\u0644\u0647 \u0627\u0644\u0630\u064a \u0622\u062a\u0627\u0643\u0645 \u0648\u0644\u0627 \u062a\u0643\u0631\u0647\u0648\u0627 \u0641\u062a\u064a\u0627\u062a\u0643\u0645 \u0639\u0644\u0649 \u0627\u0644\u0628\u063a\u0627\u0621 \u0625\u0646 \u0623\u0631\u062f\u0646 \u062a\u062d\u0635\u0646\u0627 \u0644\u062a\u0628\u062a\u063a\u0648\u0627 \u0639\u0631\u0636 \u0627\u0644\u062d\u064a\u0627\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u062f\u0646\u064a\u0627 \u0648\u0645\u0646 \u064a\u0643\u0631\u0647\u0647\u0646 \u0641\u0625\u0646 \u0627\u0644\u0644\u0647 \u0645\u0646 \u0628\u0639\u062f \u0625\u0643\u0631\u0627\u0647\u0647\u0646 \u063a\u0641\u0648\u0631 \u0631\u062d\u064a\u0645", "prev_aya": {"sura_arabic": "\u0627\u0644\u0646\u0648\u0631", "text": "\u0648\u064e\u0623\u064e\u0646\u0652\u0643\u0650\u062d\u064f\u0648\u0627 \u0627\u0644\u0652\u0623\u064e\u064a\u064e\u0627\u0645\u064e\u0649 \u0645\u0650\u0646\u0652\u0643\u064f\u0645\u0652 \u0648\u064e\u0627\u0644\u0635\u0651\u064e\u0627\u0644\u0650\u062d\u0650\u064a\u0646\u064e \u0645\u0650\u0646\u0652 \u0639\u0650\u0628\u064e\u0627\u062f\u0650\u0643\u064f\u0645\u0652 \u0648\u064e\u0625\u0650\u0645\u064e\u0627\u0626\u0650\u0643\u064f\u0645\u0652 \u0625\u0650\u0646\u0652 \u064a\u064e\u0643\u064f\u0648\u0646\u064f\u0648\u0627 \u0641\u064f\u0642\u064e\u0631\u064e\u0627\u0621\u064e \u064a\u064f\u063a\u0652\u0646\u0650\u0647\u0650\u0645\u064f \u0627\u0644\u0644\u0651\u064e\u0647\u064f \u0645\u0650\u0646\u0652 \u0641\u064e\u0636\u0652\u0644\u0650\u0647\u0650 \u0648\u064e\u0627\u0644\u0644\u0651\u064e\u0647\u064f \u0648\u064e\u0627\u0633\u0650\u0639\u064c \u0639\u064e\u0644\u0650\u064a\u0645\u064c", "sura": "An-Nur", "id": 32}, "recitation": "https://www.everyayah.com/data/Abdul_Basit_Murattal_64kbps/024033.mp3", "translation": null, "text": "\u0648\u064e\u0644\u0652\u064a\u064e\u0633\u0652\u062a\u064e\u0639\u0652\u0641\u0650\u0641\u0650 \u0627\u0644\u0651\u064e\u0630\u0650\u064a\u0646\u064e \u0644\u064e\u0627 \u064a\u064e\u062c\u0650\u062f\u064f\u0648\u0646\u064e \u0646\u0650\u0643\u064e\u0627\u062d\u064b\u0627 \u062d\u064e\u062a\u0651\u064e\u0649 \u064a\u064f\u063a\u0652\u0646\u0650\u064a\u064e\u0647\u064f\u0645\u064f \u0627\u0644\u0644\u0651\u064e\u0647\u064f \u0645\u0650\u0646\u0652 \u0641\u064e\u0636\u0652\u0644\u0650\u0647\u0650 \u0648\u064e\u0627\u0644\u0651\u064e\u0630\u0650\u064a\u0646\u064e \u064a\u064e\u0628\u0652\u062a\u064e\u063a\u064f\u0648\u0646\u064e \u0627\u0644\u0652\u0643\u0650\u062a\u064e\u0627\u0628\u064e \u0645\u0650\u0645\u0651\u064e\u0627 \u0645\u064e\u0644\u064e\u0643\u064e\u062a\u0652 \u0623\u064e\u064a\u0652\u0645\u064e\u0627\u0646\u064f\u0643\u064f\u0645\u0652 \u0641\u064e\u0643\u064e\u0627\u062a\u0650\u0628\u064f\u0648\u0647\u064f\u0645\u0652 \u0625\u0650\u0646\u0652 \u0639\u064e\u0644\u0650\u0645\u0652\u062a\u064f\u0645\u0652 \u0641\u0650\u064a\u0647\u0650\u0645\u0652 \u062e\u064e\u064a\u0652\u0631\u064b\u0627 \u0648\u064e\u0622\u062a\u064f\u0648\u0647\u064f\u0645\u0652 \u0645\u0650\u0646\u0652 \u0645\u064e\u0627\u0644\u0650 \u0627\u0644\u0644\u0651\u064e\u0647\u0650 \u0627\u0644\u0651\u064e\u0630\u0650\u064a \u0622\u062a\u064e\u0627\u0643\u064f\u0645\u0652 \u0648\u064e\u0644\u064e\u0627 <span class=\"match term0\">\u062a\u064f\u0643\u0652\u0631\u0650\u0647\u064f\u0648\u0627</span> \u0641\u064e\u062a\u064e\u064a\u064e\u0627\u062a\u0650\u0643\u064f\u0645\u0652 \u0639\u064e\u0644\u064e\u0649 \u0627\u0644\u0652\u0628\u0650\u063a\u064e\u0627\u0621\u0650 \u0625\u0650\u0646\u0652 \u0623\u064e\u0631\u064e\u062f\u0652\u0646\u064e \u062a\u064e\u062d\u064e\u0635\u0651\u064f\u0646\u064b\u0627 \u0644\u0650\u062a\u064e\u0628\u0652\u062a\u064e\u063a\u064f\u0648\u0627 \u0639\u064e\u0631\u064e\u0636\u064e \u0627\u0644\u0652\u062d\u064e\u064a\u064e\u0627\u0629\u0650 \u0627\u0644\u062f\u0651\u064f\u0646\u0652\u064a\u064e\u0627 \u0648\u064e\u0645\u064e\u0646\u0652 <span class=\"match term1\">\u064a\u064f\u0643\u0652\u0631\u0650\u0647\u0652\u0647\u064f\u0646\u0651\u064e</span> \u0641\u064e\u0625\u0650\u0646\u0651\u064e \u0627\u0644\u0644\u0651\u064e\u0647\u064e \u0645\u0650\u0646\u0652 \u0628\u064e\u0639\u0652\u062f\u0650 \u0625\u0650\u0643\u0652\u0631\u064e\u0627\u0647\u0650\u0647\u0650\u0646\u0651\u064e \u063a\u064e\u0641\u064f\u0648\u0631\u064c \u0631\u064e\u062d\u0650\u064a\u0645\u064c"}, "position": {}, "sajda": {"type": null, "exist": false, "id": null}, "annotations": {}, "sura": {}}, "4": {"stat": {"godnames": 1, "letters": 35, "words": 8}, "identifier": {"sura_name": "Muhammad", "sura_arabic_name": "\u0645\u062d\u0645\u062f", "aya_id": 9, "sura_id": 47, "gid": 4554}, "theme": {"topic": "\u0627\u0644\u0643\u0641\u0631 \u0648\u0627\u0644\u0643\u0627\u0641\u0631\u0648\u0646", "subtopic": "\u0627\u0644\u0643\u0641\u0631 \u064a\u062d\u0628\u0637 \u0627\u0644\u0639\u0645\u0644", "chapter": "\u062a\u0642\u0631\u064a\u0631 \u0627\u0644\u062a\u0648\u062d\u064a\u062f \u0648\u0628\u0637\u0644\u0627\u0646 \u0627\u0644\u0634\u0631\u0643 \u0648\u0627\u0644\u0643\u0641\u0631 "}, "aya": {"id": 9, "next_aya": {"sura_arabic": "\u0645\u062d\u0645\u062f", "text": "\u0623\u064e\u0641\u064e\u0644\u064e\u0645\u0652\u064a\u064e\u0633\u0650\u064a\u0631\u064f\u0648\u0627 \u0641\u0650\u064a \u0627\u0644\u0652\u0623\u064e\u0631\u0652\u0636\u0650 \u0641\u064e\u064a\u064e\u0646\u0652\u0638\u064f\u0631\u064f\u0648\u0627 \u0643\u064e\u064a\u0652\u0641\u064e \u0643\u064e\u0627\u0646\u064e \u0639\u064e\u0627\u0642\u0650\u0628\u064e\u0629\u064f \u0627\u0644\u0651\u064e\u0630\u0650\u064a\u0646\u064e \u0645\u0650\u0646\u0652\u0642\u064e\u0628\u0652\u0644\u0650\u0647\u0650\u0645\u0652\u062f\u064e\u0645\u0651\u064e\u0631\u064e \u0627\u0644\u0644\u0651\u064e\u0647\u064f \u0639\u064e\u0644\u064e\u064a\u0652\u0647\u0650\u0645\u0652\u0648\u064e\u0644\u0650\u0644\u0652\u0643\u064e\u0627\u0641\u0650\u0631\u0650\u064a\u0646\u064e \u0623\u064e\u0645\u0652\u062b\u064e\u0627\u0644\u064f\u0647\u064e\u0627", "sura": "Muhammad", "id": 10}, "text_no_highlight": "\u0630\u0644\u0643 \u0628\u0623\u0646\u0647\u0645 \u0643\u0631\u0647\u0648\u0627 \u0645\u0627 \u0623\u0646\u0632\u0644 \u0627\u0644\u0644\u0647 \u0641\u0623\u062d\u0628\u0637 \u0623\u0639\u0645\u0627\u0644\u0647\u0645", "prev_aya": {"sura_arabic": "\u0645\u062d\u0645\u062f", "text": "\u0648\u064e\u0627\u0644\u0651\u064e\u0630\u0650\u064a\u0646\u064e \u0643\u064e\u0641\u064e\u0631\u064f\u0648\u0627 \u0641\u064e\u062a\u064e\u0639\u0652\u0633\u064b\u0627 \u0644\u064e\u0647\u064f\u0645\u0652\u0648\u064e\u0623\u064e\u0636\u064e\u0644\u0651\u064e\u0623\u064e\u0639\u0652\u0645\u064e\u0627\u0644\u064e\u0647\u064f\u0645\u0652", "sura": "Muhammad", "id": 8}, "recitation": "https://www.everyayah.com/data/Abdul_Basit_Murattal_64kbps/047009.mp3", "translation": null, "text": "\u0630\u064e\u0644\u0650\u0643\u064e \u0628\u0650\u0623\u064e\u0646\u0651\u064e\u0647\u064f\u0645\u0652 <span class=\"match term0\">\u0643\u064e\u0631\u0650\u0647\u064f\u0648\u0627</span> \u0645\u064e\u0627 \u0623\u064e\u0646\u0652\u0632\u064e\u0644\u064e \u0627\u0644\u0644\u0651\u064e\u0647\u064f \u0641\u064e\u0623\u064e\u062d\u0652\u0628\u064e\u0637\u064e \u0623\u064e\u0639\u0652\u0645\u064e\u0627\u0644\u064e\u0647\u064f\u0645\u0652"}, "position": {}, "sajda": {"type": null, "exist": false, "id": null}, "annotations": {}, "sura": {}}, "5": {"stat": {"godnames": 1, "letters": 48, "words": 10}, "identifier": {"sura_name": "Muhammad", "sura_arabic_name": "\u0645\u062d\u0645\u062f", "aya_id": 28, "sura_id": 47, "gid": 4573}, "theme": {"topic": "\u0645\u0644\u0627\u0626\u0643\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0648\u062a", "subtopic": null, "chapter": "\u0623\u0631\u0643\u0627\u0646 \u0627\u0644\u0625\u064a\u0645\u0627\u0646"}, "aya": {"id": 28, "next_aya": {"sura_arabic": "\u0645\u062d\u0645\u062f", "text": "\u0623\u064e\u0645\u0652 \u062d\u064e\u0633\u0650\u0628\u064e \u0627\u0644\u0651\u064e\u0630\u0650\u064a\u0646\u064e \u0641\u0650\u064a \u0642\u064f\u0644\u064f\u0648\u0628\u0650\u0647\u0650\u0645\u0652 \u0645\u064e\u0631\u064e\u0636\u064c \u0623\u064e\u0646\u0652 \u0644\u064e\u0646\u0652 \u064a\u064f\u062e\u0652\u0631\u0650\u062c\u064e \u0627\u0644\u0644\u0651\u064e\u0647\u064f \u0623\u064e\u0636\u0652\u063a\u064e\u0627\u0646\u064e\u0647\u064f\u0645\u0652", "sura": "Muhammad", "id": 29}, "text_no_highlight": "\u0630\u0644\u0643 \u0628\u0623\u0646\u0647\u0645 \u0627\u062a\u0628\u0639\u0648\u0627 \u0645\u0627 \u0623\u0633\u062e\u0637 \u0627\u0644\u0644\u0647 \u0648\u0643\u0631\u0647\u0648\u0627 \u0631\u0636\u0648\u0627\u0646\u0647 \u0641\u0623\u062d\u0628\u0637 \u0623\u0639\u0645\u0627\u0644\u0647\u0645", "prev_aya": {"sura_arabic": "\u0645\u062d\u0645\u062f", "text": "\u0641\u064e\u0643\u064e\u064a\u0652\u0641\u064e \u0625\u0650\u0630\u064e\u0627 \u062a\u064e\u0648\u064e\u0641\u0651\u064e\u062a\u0652\u0647\u064f\u0645\u064f \u0627\u0644\u0652\u0645\u064e\u0644\u064e\u0627\u0626\u0650\u0643\u064e\u0629\u064f \u064a\u064e\u0636\u0652\u0631\u0650\u0628\u064f\u0648\u0646\u064e \u0648\u064f\u062c\u064f\u0648\u0647\u064e\u0647\u064f\u0645\u0652 \u0648\u064e\u0623\u064e\u062f\u0652\u0628\u064e\u0627\u0631\u064e\u0647\u064f\u0645\u0652", "sura": "Muhammad", "id": 27}, "recitation": "https://www.everyayah.com/data/Abdul_Basit_Murattal_64kbps/047028.mp3", "translation": null, "text": "\u0630\u064e\u0644\u0650\u0643\u064e \u0628\u0650\u0623\u064e\u0646\u0651\u064e\u0647\u064f\u0645\u064f \u0627\u062a\u0651\u064e\u0628\u064e\u0639\u064f\u0648\u0627 \u0645\u064e\u0627 \u0623\u064e\u0633\u0652\u062e\u064e\u0637\u064e \u0627\u0644\u0644\u0651\u064e\u0647\u064e <span class=\"match term0\">\u0648\u064e\u0643\u064e\u0631\u0650\u0647\u064f\u0648\u0627</span> \u0631\u0650\u0636\u0652\u0648\u064e\u0627\u0646\u064e\u0647\u064f \u0641\u064e\u0623\u064e\u062d\u0652\u0628\u064e\u0637\u064e \u0623\u064e\u0639\u0652\u0645\u064e\u0627\u0644\u064e\u0647\u064f\u0645\u0652"}, "position": {}, "sajda": {"type": null, "exist": false, "id": null}, "annotations": {}, "sura": {}}, "10": {"stat": {"godnames": 1, "letters": 37, "words": 8}, "identifier": {"sura_name": "Ghafir", "sura_arabic_name": "\u063a\u0627\u0641\u0631", "aya_id": 14, "sura_id": 40, "gid": 4147}, "theme": {"topic": "\u0625\u062e\u0644\u0627\u0635 \u0627\u0644\u0639\u0645\u0644 \u0644\u0644\u0647 ", "subtopic": null, "chapter": "\u0634\u0639\u0628 \u0627\u0644\u0625\u064a\u0645\u0627\u0646 "}, "aya": {"id": 14, "next_aya": {"sura_arabic": "\u063a\u0627\u0641\u0631", "text": "\u0631\u064e\u0641\u0650\u064a\u0639\u064f \u0627\u0644\u062f\u0651\u064e\u0631\u064e\u062c\u064e\u0627\u062a\u0650 \u0630\u064f\u0648 \u0627\u0644\u0652\u0639\u064e\u0631\u0652\u0634\u0650 \u064a\u064f\u0644\u0652\u0642\u0650\u064a \u0627\u0644\u0631\u0651\u064f\u0648\u062d\u064e \u0645\u0650\u0646\u0652 \u0623\u064e\u0645\u0652\u0631\u0650\u0647\u0650 \u0639\u064e\u0644\u064e\u0649 \u0645\u064e\u0646\u0652 \u064a\u064e\u0634\u064e\u0627\u0621\u064f \u0645\u0650\u0646\u0652 \u0639\u0650\u0628\u064e\u0627\u062f\u0650\u0647\u0650 \u0644\u0650\u064a\u064f\u0646\u0652\u0630\u0650\u0631\u064e \u064a\u064e\u0648\u0652\u0645\u064e \u0627\u0644\u062a\u0651\u064e\u0644\u064e\u0627\u0642\u0650", "sura": "Ghafir", "id": 15}, "text_no_highlight": "\u0641\u0627\u062f\u0639\u0648\u0627 \u0627\u0644\u0644\u0647 \u0645\u062e\u0644\u0635\u064a\u0646 \u0644\u0647 \u0627\u0644\u062f\u064a\u0646 \u0648\u0644\u0648 \u0643\u0631\u0647 \u0627\u0644\u0643\u0627\u0641\u0631\u0648\u0646", "prev_aya": {"sura_arabic": "\u063a\u0627\u0641\u0631", "text": "\u0647\u064f\u0648\u064e\u0627\u0644\u0651\u064e\u0630\u0650\u064a \u064a\u064f\u0631\u0650\u064a\u0643\u064f\u0645\u0652 \u0622\u064a\u064e\u0627\u062a\u0650\u0647\u0650 \u0648\u064e\u064a\u064f\u0646\u064e\u0632\u0651\u0650\u0644\u064f \u0644\u064e\u0643\u064f\u0645\u0652 \u0645\u0650\u0646\u064e\u0627\u0644\u0633\u0651\u064e\u0645\u064e\u0627\u0621\u0650 \u0631\u0650\u0632\u0652\u0642\u064b\u0627\u0648\u064e\u0645\u064e\u0627 \u064a\u064e\u062a\u064e\u0630\u064e\u0643\u0651\u064e\u0631\u064f \u0625\u0650\u0644\u0651\u064e\u0627\u0645\u064e\u0646\u0652\u064a\u064f\u0646\u0650\u064a\u0628\u064f", "sura": "Ghafir", "id": 13}, "recitation": "https://www.everyayah.com/data/Abdul_Basit_Murattal_64kbps/040014.mp3", "translation": null, "text": "\u0641\u064e\u0627\u062f\u0652\u0639\u064f\u0648\u0627 \u0627\u0644\u0644\u0651\u064e\u0647\u064e \u0645\u064f\u062e\u0652\u0644\u0650\u0635\u0650\u064a\u0646\u064e \u0644\u064e\u0647\u064f \u0627\u0644\u062f\u0651\u0650\u064a\u0646\u064e \u0648\u064e\u0644\u064e\u0648\u0652 <span class=\"match term0\">\u0643\u064e\u0631\u0650\u0647\u064e</span> \u0627\u0644\u0652\u0643\u064e\u0627\u0641\u0650\u0631\u064f\u0648\u0646\u064e"}, "position": {}, "sajda": {"type": null, "exist": false, "id": null}, "annotations": {}, "sura": {}}}, "translation_info": {}, "words": {"individual": {}}, "runtime": 0.14392}]
```

you can use this link to formating your JSON and catch the issues
https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#

Comment: You should specify the steps you took to correct the string. The OP looks like they are already using a linter but cannot determine the issue from the message.

Comment: I used the link to formating the JSON and it gave where the issue is it

Comment: Yes, but it points to the same line and gives an equally unhelpful message. OP has already placed their JSON into a different parser in order to get the error message provided and that has not solved their problem. You should say what was wrong with the string, not just a repeat of what OP knows. The "text" property is invalid, but _why_.

Comment: you can see here how I manage it (https://ibb.co/C1SJ9Cj)
you can note where the position of the issue and then you have to find where the issue
You can't have everything ready without making an effort and tracking :)